# Icon is not triggering the function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so this is basically exactly the code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp
I have everything working except for some reason I cannot get the hamburger icon to load the other menu links when clicked... I've tried everything and have stared at it till my eyes are square, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My HTML:

```
     <body style= margin:20%;>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PeterPanStyle.css"> 


    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
         <a href="Cover.html">Home</a>
         <a href="About.html"> About</a>
         <a href="XContents.html"> Contents</a>
         <a href="#">Glossary </a>
         <a href="#">Quiz! </a>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>

     </div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += "responsive";
} else {
    x.className = "topnav";
}
</script>
```

My CSS:

```
   .topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;
   }

   .topnav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
  }

.topnav .icon {
display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
 .topnav a.icon {
float: right;
display: block;
 }
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
   }
  .topnav.responsive a {
float: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

 }
```

Comment: *"What is wrong with my Java?"* - Well for one thing it isn't Java, it's JavaScript, an unrelated language.

Comment: The W3Schools page doesn't say `<body style= margin:20%>` either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing curly brace at the end of the Javascript myFunction().

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += "responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

Comment: You can look into using what is called a linter on your code. These programs check your code for things like this as you write.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your code and the example code is a space. Add a space when you set the className property.

```
x.className += " responsive";
```

Comment: @AleshaHonnor try adding `}` at the end of your `javascript`. It would appear you haven't closed your function. If you open the browser console you will be able to find error reports to help identify problems.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not functional for three reasons.

1. It is not valid html.
2. You need to add a space before responsive. `x.className += " responsive";`

You need a space since this line of code is appending (`+=`) a string of text to the current class attribute of your element.  Your div class will now become `class="topnavresponsive">` instead of `class="topnavresponsive">`

3. There is a missing `}` at the end of your JavaScript function.

Your valid html should look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PeterPanStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="Cover.html">Home</a>
        <a href="About.html"> About</a>
        <a href="XContents.html"> Contents</a>
        <a href="#">Glossary </a>
        <a href="#">Quiz! </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My actual code does have all the valid thing I just copied the problem areas of my code because its quite a lot of text to bring all over when only a certain amount is relevant :)